# Shell commands working from PuTTy but not from Shell script File

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to execute the below shell commands from PuTTY

```
PACKAGEPATH=/data/dev/bwan/deliveryPackage
RELEASENAME=R201709TEST3
PACKAGEFINALPATH=$PACKAGEPATH/$RELEASENAME
echo $PACKAGEPATH
echo $RELEASENAME
echo $PACKAGEFINALPATH
```

and I get the desired output as

```
/data/dev/bwan/deliveryPackage
R201709TEST3
/data/dev/bwan/deliveryPackage/R201709TEST3
```

However, If I am putting the same steps in a shell File and then executing that shell Script, it is giving me unexpected responses as

```
/data/dev/bwan/deliveryPackage
R201709TEST3
/R201709TEST3n/deliveryPackage
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It sure works as a sh or bash script. What exactly is your environment? Are you sure you are executing the correct script, as the script is simple and there is no reason why it would not work on any sh variant.

Comment: Your script file has `\r\n` line endings. Fix it with `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's/\r$//' file`. Prevent the problem by configuring your editor to use just LF line endings

Comment: It's bad practice to use ALLCAPSVARNAMES. One day you'll use `PATH=something` and then wonder why your script is broken. Leave ALLCAPSVARNAMES for the shell.